# Sharepoint 2010: how to populate a selection box with list views?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am having a hard time figuring this one out... my goal is to place a list view picker on the title bar of every list webpart or at least in a more obvious place in the the list page.(it is inconvenient, not user-intuitive/friendly and plain annoying under the top ribbon to say the least...). something similar to what we had in SP2007.

Does anyone know how it could be achieved?

thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a Content Editor WebPart with a roll-your-own HTML drop down of the urls that lead to each view (aspx). If you can make it dynamic if you're feeling all codey :)

Comment: yeah that's the basic idea. I wanted a more elaborate solution that will dynamically populate the <select> tag according to whatever view there is or will be in the list. thought I am really unsure how to find out what views the list has in a programmatic way. I am sure there is a built-in SP class that does this function already... I am just not familiar with the SP API.

Comment: If it was me, I'd use jQuery and SPServices, using the GetViewCollection method. Maybe 10 lines of javascript. http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Views&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices

Answer (score 0):

SP 2010 has the same view picker as SP 2007. You just need to enable it in the Web Part settings (enable full toolbar).